# What are the differences between mdframed vs. tcolorbox

Tags: packages, mdframed, tcolorbox, comparison

I am familiar with [the `mdframed` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) and its usefulness when content crosses page boundaries.  But lately, I have seen quite a few questions about [the `tcolorbox` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) and don't know much about it so am wondering:

1. What are the basic differences between these two packages?
2. What kinds of scenarios should one prefer one over the other, and 
   which cases should one stay away from particular package?